# Rails session not persisting after redirects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using session store to save data into sessions. My initializers/session_store.rb looks like as:

```
::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store
```

Adding data to session code:

```
book = Book.find(1)
session[:abc] = book
```

I am accessing this session data at a different page. Accessing session data:

```
book = session[:abc]
```

Problem is that my session data is not persisted between redirects. What could be the problem?

I can see that my session is saving the data as expected but it lost some data from it when redirect happens and lost even more if again redirect happens. Frustrating it is.

Comment: You should add some information about how you are writing into, and reading from, the session.  Ie, the code which isn't giving the results you expect.

Comment: @MaxWilliams, I thought it would be understandable. Anyway, I have edited my question. What now?

Comment: please you post your controller code

Comment: @MaxWilliams, Were you able to help him on this?

Comment: @AmitSharma, I am also kind of struck with same problem.

Comment: have you tried by replacing this `::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store`  with `Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_your_project_name'` in your initializers/session_store.rb

Comment: @AmitSharma Already tried but did not help.

Comment: Do you see it adds records to the database?

Comment: @RahulBhargava have you tried it by sending only book id in session e.g. `session[:abc] = book.id` and access it in another page `book = Book.find(session[:abc])`

Comment: Is this really rails 4? Are you using the `activerecord-session_store` gem?

Comment: Why are you trying to store the whole book object in your session in the first place? Just store the id and then reload it.

Comment: @EvgenyPetrov : I am sorry. As far I understood your question, it did not add records to the database.

Comment: @Mario : Ohh is there that kind of gem too? Anyway, I am not using any gem. All I am doing for session storage is :

In config/initializers/session_store.rb : 
`<Application_Name>::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store`

Comment: @RahulBhargava Did you run `rake db:sessions:create` and `rake db:migrate` ?

Comment: @tirdadc. Well, as I said earlier, it works. But that is not what I want.

Suppose a situation like : You enter data at page a, which is redirecting to page b. On submit of page b, you need to save the data of page a as well. That's why I am using sessions to save data of page a when I redirect it to page b. Then access those session on submit of page b and store into the records. I do not know if that is the best optimal solution to do under this situation but I am sure it should work.

Comment: On curiosity note, how much is the allowed limit for sessions? 4kb is for cookie store.

Comment: @RahulBhargava max `:text` or `:longtext` limit, depending on the database used, around 65Kb, it will [raise an exception](https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store/blob/master/lib/active_record/session_store/session.rb#L90) if you try to save more than that.

Comment: Obvious question. Is the redirect happening on the same domain?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this
pass book id to session instead of whole book object.

e.g.

in **page A**

```
book = Book.find(1)
session[:abc] = book.id
```

in **page B**

```
book = Book.find(session[:abc])
```

Answer (score 4):

Didn't you forget to add sessions table?

```
rails g active_record:session_migration
rake db:migrate
```

Comment: I have sessions table in mySql database.

Comment: Strange, that should be enough for it to work... I'll give it a try later.

Comment: And the page you redirect to is in the same subdomain?

Comment: @RahulBhargava I just have set up a small app, minimal steps required are: *1)* switch to `:active_record_store` *2)* add migration and migrate(as in my answer) *3)* add `gem 'activerecord-session_store'` to the Gemfile. In case you want to try to find a difference  I've put my app [here](https://app.box.com/s/yz8a46xh93xejn5a9uqjqwhw4cr273n3) (`index#first` sets `session[:abc]` to `Book.first` and redirects to `index#second` which shows `session[:abc].name`)

Answer (score 3):

You can write a method in Book model.

```
def self.current=(book)                
  Thread.current[:current_book] = book  
end

def self.current  
  Thread.current[:current_book]  
end
```

Adding data to session code,

```
book = Book.find(1)  
Book.current = book
```

And, to access book from session, you can call  method

```
Book.current
```

Comment: can you plz explain why did you use thread for setting and  accessing values ?