# Rails 4 session not persisting across requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My Rails 3.2 application has a controller called LaunchController that provides an api for other web applications so they can embed quizzes generated and scored in my application.

When an external application posts to the LaunchController, `LaunchController#create` authenticates using OAuth, caches an object `@tool` that knows about the external application, stores a cache key in the session `session[:launch_tool_cache_key]`  and  redirects to another controller `AttemptsController#new` that renders a quiz.  When the user submits their answers, AttemptsControllert#create grades their quiz and uses @tool to posts a grade back to the external application.

Everything works fine in 3.2.

Last week I (finally!) upgraded my app to Rails 4.2.  I sorted the rest of the migration and the application now works in development.  Except for this process.

The problem lies in persisting the `session[:launch_tool_cache_key]` that contains the key I use to retrieve the serialized `@tool` from the cache so I can then send the grade back to the external application.  My logs show that the cache key gets stored in the `LaunchController`, but after the redirect to `AttemptsController#new` the session key is gone.

Things I have tried:

- commenting out `protect_from_forgery`
- adding `skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token`

Comment: My guess (and this is really just a guess): the new [strong_parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) is causing this somehow by some logic in your application somewhere... Blocked parameters should be logged, so check the `log/development.log` for this.

Comment: Did you find any solution for it?

Comment: @DeepanshuGoyal I did not.  I decided to keep the code in 3.2 until the app was shut down.

Answer (score 1):

It could be some problem with saving an object to a session key. Look here

[Rails session not persisting after redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29543448/rails-session-not-persisting-after-redirects)

This issue looks like similar to yours.

If so, it seems like you'd better store your `@tool` into database (it could be Redis for example), store one's key to session and retrieve it by key after redirection.

If this doesn't help, please, provide some more detailed explanation (maybe with some pieces of code)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  However, I decided to keep the code in 3.2 since the application is sunsetting in the near future.

Comment: @vlasits He did answer your question.

Comment: @msbarnard True.  And he definitely provided me with a good tip on debugging the issue.  However, since I did not attempt to implement the solution he suggested I don't have the confirmation that would be necessary for me to accept it as the correct answer or upvote it or downvote.  He'll just have to live my written expression of gratitude for the effort he put into his answer.